# AAD B2C Custom Policies example not returning email claim for username based sign in

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the instructions of [Deploy AAD B2C Custom Policies](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/) to deploy custom policies in my B2C directory.

I have deployed successfully the [Username based journey](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin) quick deploy sample.

When running the endpoint of `B2C_1A_DEMO_SUSI_USERNAME`.

- A signup returns the `email` claim.
- A signin doesn't return the `email` claim.

For the signin process to return the `email` claim,
do I modify the Technical Profile with ID `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username` of the `B2C_1A_DEMO_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS_USERNAME` custom policy? And if so, what exactly should I add? And if not, what else should I look at?

Technical Profile `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username`:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And for comparison, this is the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName` Technical Profile which returns the `email` claim:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
    <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I have tried to add `email` as an Output Claim with the following line of code,

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
```

But it results in an exception error, I do not have insights enabled yet to trace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the sample:

"At Sign Up, the user is asked to validate an email address. This email address will be associated to the user account by writing to a protected attribute: strongAuthenticationEmailAddress".

So you need to output "strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" in "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username" and in the RP.

If you want to output "email" in the RP:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress"" PartnerClaimType="email" Required="true" />
```

should work.

Comment: The relying party (RP) for this is `SignUpOrSignInWithUsername` in the `B2C_1A_DEMO_SUSI_USERNAME` custom policy and it already contains the following. `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />`. Is this okay and enough?

Comment: No - at sign-in "email" is not populated because you sign in with username. So you have to read the user record and then use the partner claim to "copy" strongauth to email. What it actually does is rename the strongauth claim to email in the JWT.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
Added `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />` for the `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username` Technical Profile and `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />` for the relying party.

Answer (score 0):

> A signin doesn't return the email claim.

If the claim was added after the signin had been provisioned, subsequent logins will by the *old* provisined user will not have that claim. Delete any singins that proceeded the adding of said claim and have them re-provision themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as I understand this is not the scenario for this situation since it has always been stored as `strongAuthenticationEmailAddress` but just not put in technical profile as an output. Anyway very useful information to keep in mind.

Comment: It was an edge case, but thought I would throw it out there...it happened to me. GL